# Numpy unique elements according to every column

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a way to reduce a `Nx2` numpy matrix to a smaller matrix where each number occurs in every column only once.

For example:

```
A = np.array([[2, 0],
              [1, 0],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 1],
              [1, 3],
              [1, 2]])
# Would be output as
[[2, 0],
 [0, 1],
 [1, 3]]
```

Order must be maintained (the first case where each number occurs must be the one used).

A python implementation for this is:

```
output = []
x_occurances = set()
y_occurances = set()
for x, y in A:
    if x not in x_occurances and y not in y_occurances:
        output.append([x, y])
        x_occurances.add(x)
        y_occurances.add(y)
```

But I would like to know if a more numpy-centric solution exists. I was looking at `np.unique()` however cases I find only seem to work over unique rows or columns.

Comment: Shouldn't your output contain 2 in second column?

Comment: @shivsn I would say no, because a row is only kept if **both** numbers in it have not yet been ouputed in their respective column, so when you reach `[1,2]` the output already contains `[2, 0],[0, 1] and [1, 3]`  so column 0 already has a 1 hence the row is rejected.

Comment: @jadsq yes, that's correct.

Comment: Your uniqueness criteria is too specialized.  Treating it as a list of tuples as you do seems to be the the only way.